# Spring statemachine JPA config- can we call non-static methods using SpEL expressions in Action table?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-statemachine

I want to store state machine definition in database, and I am using the JPA Config sample to build a prototype with H2 in-memory database.

Everything seems to be working fine. However, I can only call a static method using SpEL expression in Action table. If I try to call any other method I get the error "Method execStaticAction() cannot be found on type org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateContext". I've tried singleton, and instance methods as well. But I keep getting the same error. Is this allowed, or can we only call static methods using SpEL expressions in Action table?

Here's the sample I'm using:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-examples-datajpa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JpaRepositoryAction.action column is the name of the bean method being executed that returns an Action object.